# Performance degrading when more threads/processes takes cores even when not all cores are used

Tags: linux, multithreading, multicore

To explore the CPU performance on Ubuntu, I'm using `sysbench`'s `cpu` test. I'm also using `taskset` to bind certain CPUs to a process.

The script I used to run the experiment is as below:

```
for concur in {1..24}
do
    end=$(($concur-1))
    echo "--> Create $concur jobs"

    for i in $(seq 0 $end)
    do
        j=`expr $i \\* 2`
        taskset -c $j-$(($j+1)) sysbench --test=cpu --cpu-max-prime=200000 --num-threads=2 run > sysbench-cpu-$concur-$i.out &
        pids[${i}]=$!
    done

    echo "--> Waiting for ${pids[*]}"
    for pid in ${pids[*]}; do
        wait $pid
    done
    unset pids
    echo "--> Clean up ${pids[*]}"
done
```

I have a 48-core server so the maximum threads does not exceed number of cores.

Now the results are:

```
Concurrent Jobs | Average Time For Each Job(s)
1   331.8708
2   342.1978
3   354.9352333
4   360.505625
5   363.86354
6   363.632
7   363.9364429
8   363.761375
9   365.1571667
10  365.81912
11  366.2094909
12  366.56025
13  377.9281923
14  388.7300214
15  398.2705067
16  406.7716438
17  414.7786471
18  422.2813444
19  429.1379421
20  434.907065
21  440.5540571
22  445.3167864
23  450.0088783
24  456.5647417
```

As the results show, the time is increasing when more jobs are running. But why?

As the job is solely CPU-bound job, and in sysbench, the job is just each thread computing prime up to `--cpu-max-prime`, so no locking, besides it's not even taking memory to store array. I know when too many cores are taken, threads can be scheduled off for other system threads, but here, when moderate jobs are spawned, for example 10 jobs which take 20 cores, the performance is still worse than 1 job.

Comment: What are the timings without affinity or within one process?

Comment: @zch without affinity, they are similar. What do you mean within one process?

Comment: Similar means affinity makes no difference? Within one process I meant `--num-threads=48`.